# How to scroll Jqgrid fixed header row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have jqgrid with dynamic data but the major issue is data is so much so it needs a horizontally scroll to view all data and that behavior is mandatory but when is fix that header it can't scroll. i need that header scroll as well.

i set position : "fixed";

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a wrapper div for your jqgrid. Like:

```
<div id='gridwrapper' class='gridWrapper'>
    <table id='grid'><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id='gridPager'></div>
</div>
```

set the css for `gridWrapper`:

```
.gridWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    overflow:auto; /* <---set the overflow to auto*/
}
```

---

What happens when you create jqgrid, it generates/creates two tables one for the headers and one for the creating/displaying data rows. So, by default only data rows would be scrolled not the headers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been a year old question.
But I found this working for me.
JQGrid create 2 `<DIV>`: one for Header and other for Body.
By Default JQGrid assigns the Body `<div>` as 100%.
So change the height of ui-jqgrid-bdiv.

Please see the attached snapshot.
[image]